# pm AutoARIMA no suitable models found

Tags: python, arima, pmdarima

I am trying to create a seasonal ARIMA (SARIMA) model using pmdarima's AutoARIMA. The reason for that is that new data will become available over the lifetime of the project and code is required which automatically finds the best timeseries model. Unfortunately my current code seems to be producing garbage:

```
import pmdarima as pm
import pandas as pd


train_data = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=None, names=["Value"])["Value"]
model = pm.AutoARIMA(seasonal=True, m=168, trace=True)
model.fit(train_data.fillna(0))
```

[test.csv](https://rwth-aachen.sciebo.de/s/c1sp6dbJHPtcHf9)

Output (so far, after quite some time on large server):

```
Performing stepwise search to minimize aic
 ARIMA(2,1,2)(1,0,1)[168] intercept   : AIC=inf, Time=4041.19 sec
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,0)[168] intercept   : AIC=-35451.160, Time=1.07 sec
 ARIMA(1,1,0)(1,0,0)[168] intercept   : AIC=inf, Time=15118.06 sec
 ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,1)[168] intercept   : AIC=-35951.886, Time=3805.77 sec
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,0)[168]             : AIC=-35453.123, Time=0.56 sec
 ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,0)[168] intercept   : AIC=-35723.198, Time=2.69 sec
 ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,0,1)[168] intercept   : AIC=inf, Time=61326.67 sec
 ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,2)[168] intercept   : AIC=inf, Time=39971.60 sec
 ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,0,0)[168] intercept   : AIC=-36054.745, Time=4211.60 sec
 ARIMA(0,1,1)(2,0,0)[168] intercept   : AIC=-36344.782, Time=30668.84 sec
```

The data has two seasonal patterns (one daily and one weekly). Including a daily pattern gives sensible results (using `m=24`), but weekly tends to cause `AIC=inf` as in the example above.

Comment: Is it normal that it takes that long?

Comment: The dataset is relatively large, so the long operating time was to be expected. But it could be very different in your case.

Comment: Which machine did you use? I have a very similar dataset with also a big seasonality. Because of the long computation time I switched to Facebook Prophet which is way, way faster.

Comment: The machine has 32 cores with about 64 threads and about 250GB RAM. I will probably also go for fb prophet, but wanted to have SARIMA as a backup option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to have been that pmdarima times out after some time and inserts an AIC of inf as a replacement for the non-calculated AIC. I ended up doing conventional analysis and going for a slightly oversized SARIMA model which takes longer to fit, but definitely includes all relevant effects.